# Facebook account gets locked when username-password is given to iTunesConnect

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-integration

I am in India. I made an app based on Facebook. For testing, I had to give my account details (dummy account) for testing, but this account won't work for the Apple guys because of Facebook's security. The account gets temporarily locked because of unknown location and unknown device.

How do I disable this security? Or how could I work around this problem?